# Find and copy a line using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, lines

I am new to this forum and to programming and apologize in advance if I violate any of the forum rules. I have researched this extensively, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

So I have a very long file that has this general structure:

```
data="""
   20.020001    563410   9
   20.520001    577410  20
   21.022001    591466   9
   21.522001    605466 120
   23.196001    652338   2
   25.278001    710634   7
   25.780001    724690 144
   26.280001    738690   9
   26.782001    752746  40
   27.282001    766746   9
   27.784001    780802 140
   29.372001    825266   2
   31.458001    883674   7
   31.958002    897674   8
   32.458002    911674   9
   32.958002    925674  10

"""
```

I imported the file using

```
with open("C:\blablabla\text.txt", 'r+') as infile:
data = infile.read()
```

Now I am trying to use a regular expression to find all lines that end with 140 through 146, so I did this:

```
items=re.findall('.......................14[0-6]\n',data,re.MULTILINE)
for x in items:
    print x
```

This works, but when I now try to copy those lines that contain the regular expression,

```
for x in items:
    if items in data:
        data.write(items)
```

I get the following error:

```
if items in data:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. How can I feed the left operand a string when the outcome of my regex is a list?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For whitespace-delimited text blocks of a fixed format it's often a good solution to choose `split` over `re` - e.g. `line.split()` would split a line into the separate numbers. You can then simply check if the last item, `line.split()[-1]`, is in the expected range.

Comment: Why are you checking `if items in data:`? Didn't you just extract `items` from data?

Comment: Also check out the `csv` module. It might make parsing a bit easier

Comment: Your regular expression could be better written as `r'.*?14[0-6]$'`

Comment: @Suianne : If you are certain about the correctness of the answers written below, please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply handle each line separately:

```
data = infile.readlines()
for line in data:
    if re.match('.......................14[0-6]\n', line):
        print line[:-1]
```

The last character of the line is a trailing newline, which would be duplicated by the one the `print` statement includes.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line:

```
data=""
with open("file.txt", 'r+') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if (146 >= int(line.split()[-1]) >= 140) :
            data = data + line

print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex can be simplified further

```
re.findall('.*?14[0-6]\n')
```

To overcome your further problems

```
items = re.findall('.*?14[0-6]\n',data)
result=""""""
for x in items:
     result+=str(x)
print result
```